Are there limitations on execution 'depth' or 'length' for register_shutdown_function functions?
This is a serious head-scratcher (for me at least).
I have re-structured my application to trigger issuing of email and SMS notifications regarding an action after the browser request has been responded to, in order to improve response times. I am using register_shutdown_function (and fastcgi_finish_request) for this purpose.
For simple activities performed in the register_shutdown_function handler, this works fine. However, my mailing sending process involves a lot of activity. I am finding that the execution of this activity is just stopping before completion. No errors, no exceptions, no PHP log output... just nothing.
I cannot find a timeout that would be causing this (default max_execution_time of 30 seconds is in effect, and although complex, the processing question still takes nothing like that amount of time).
I have traced this using a XDebug and the execution seems to consistently stop at the same point, but if I make a code change to comment out whatever is happening around there, the stopping point just moves on a little. It is as if there is some limit on the number of instructions that will get executed or the depth/number of function calls that will be handled, but I canot put my finger on it, and there is nothing obvious in the register_shutdown_function documentation to explain it that I can find.
Help!
For reference, this is the message spooler class I am using:
class MessageSpool {
    private static $messageQueue = [];
    private static $enqueued = false;

    public static function enqueueMail($args) {
        self::enqueueMessage(['MailUtil', 'sendMail'], $args);
    }
    
    public static function enqueueSMS($args) {
        self::enqueueMessage(['SmsUtil', 'sendSMS'], $args);
    }
  
    private static function enqueueMessage($handler, $args) {
        if (!self::$enqueued) {
            register_shutdown_function('MessageSpool::send');
            self::$enqueued = true;
        } 
        self::$messageQueue[] = compact('handler', 'args');
    }
  
    public static function send() 
    {
        fastcgi_finish_request();
        foreach(self::$messageQueue as $message) {
            call_user_func_array($message['handler'], $message['args']);
        }
    }
}


From the docs, perhaps you're experiencing this: "If you write to the buffer after calling fastcgi_finish_request(), your script will exit with no error message or exception. Calling ignore_user_abort(true) after fastcgi_finish_request() can mitigate this issue." That said, I think you're at the point where you might as well just separate the processes and instead use an async job queue, which you'll likely find much more flexible, considering the session locking and FPM-process-using alternative.

@AlexHowansky, well spotted - you've hit the nail on the head! Post this as an answer so I can accept it. In regard to your observation about using an async job queue, I was weighing this up as an option also and may yet move to that, but the current solution means one less cron job and a little less complexity to deal with. For my particular use case, an async queue would have the benefit of retries when the mail server is unavailable though, just as an aside.

As a note, cron job tend to only have slightly fewer drawbacks than putting web/FPM workers into the background. An AMQP queue and something like supervisord will let you have fine-grained control over the workers, and ensure that your async tasks are handled immediately.

I'm guessing that you're experiencing this particular situation, as described in the user notes for the fastcgi_finish_request() function:

If you write to the buffer after calling fastcgi_finish_request(), your script will exit with no error message or exception. Calling ignore_user_abort(true) after fastcgi_finish_request() can mitigate this issue.

That said, I think you're at the point where you're better off separating the request processes and the email process into distinct parts, and then using an asyncronous job queue. You'll likely find this much more flexible, considering that your existing method locks sessions and uses up an FPM-process.
If you're using Laravel then you already have them available. You might also use Zend JobQueue or Beanstalk or any of a dozen other products.
